# I keep getting Error: ResizeObserver loop limit exceeded in cypress

Tags: resize, cypress, google-signin, resize-observer

[image]

```js
Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
    return false;
    
  }
```

I added this inside my code block

```js
describe('TBoss Account Creation Credentials', () => {
  Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
    return false;
    
  });
  it('Identification Validation', () => {
    cy.visit('our website')
    cy.get('.mat-focus-indicator').click()
    cy.wait(5000)
    cy.origin('https://accounts.google.com/', () => {
      cy.get('.Xb9hP').eq(0).type('1234')
      cy.get('.VfPpkd-vQzf8d').eq(1).invoke('show').click()
      cy.wait(5000)
      cy.get('.whsOnd.zHQkBf').eq(0).type('1234', {force: true})
    })

    })
})
```

When I access our website, it redirects me to google sign in page.

I couldn't `get()` the google sign in input box in order to type the ID, so I used origin, and it works.

However, after adding origin it gives me that error.

On the google sign in page, I can successfully type the ID  then it shows the password input form and that's where this error occurs.

I want to `get()` the password input and `type()` the password and log in through google sign in form.

Comment: Try to share text: code, errors or logs as text (code block) not as image

Answer (score 4):

The origin is sandboxed from the main page.

First thing to try is to move or copy the error catcher inside the `cy.origion()`. It may not work, there are some things that can't be run in there.

```js
describe('TBoss Account Creation Credentials', () => {

  it('Identification Validation', () => {
    cy.visit('our website')
    cy.get('.mat-focus-indicator').click()
    cy.wait(5000)
    cy.origin('https://accounts.google.com/', () => {

      Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
        return false;
      });

      cy.get('.Xb9hP').eq(0).type('1234')
      cy.get('.VfPpkd-vQzf8d').eq(1).invoke('show').click()
      cy.wait(5000)
      cy.get('.whsOnd.zHQkBf').eq(0).type('1234', {force: true})
    })

  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Cypress and this issue bumps in, you can safely ignore it with the following code in support/index.js or commands.ts:

```
const resizeObserverLoopErrRe = /^[^(ResizeObserver loop limit exceeded)]/
Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err) => {
        if (resizeObserverLoopErrRe.test(err.message)) {
        return false
    }
})
```